# Highstock change xAxis minRange after chart is loaded

Tags: javascript, runtime, highcharts

I am truing to change the `minRange` on `xAxis` after chart has been loaded. i have tried these with no success :

```
chart.xAxis[0].minRange
chart.xAxis.minRange
chart.xAxis[0].options.minRange
chart.xAxis.options.minRange
```

none of them works.bu setting the `minTickInterval` like this works :

```
chart.xAxis[0].options.minTickInterval
```

so how can i change `minRange` at runtime?

UPDATE:I should have mentioned that my axis is type of datetime

UPDATE 2: ok i found the problem, i have this in my code :

```
    $.each(Analyzer.chart.series, function (index, item) {
        item.setData([]);
    });
```

to clear the series data, so i can load new data. if i comment this peace of code setting `minRange` works.

so ??? how to clear series data so that i can change `minRange` too ????

UPDATE 3: ok i moved the cod in update2 to before setting `minRange`.... and walla it works :D

> for future references : you should set `minRange` after you have
>   cleared the series data otherwise it wont works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the isDirty flag of the xAxis object, and then run the redraw method:

```
    chart.xAxis[0].minRange = 20;
    chart.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
    chart.redraw();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d2Zdh/

Edit: It should also work when your x axis is of type "datetime". 
See updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/NnW5G/